# Selecting records that are missing a birthday row or value from database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select clients that are **missing** OR has **never had a birthday** entered.  This is kind of an old system that has allowed birthday data to be: `false`, `0` OR `[blank]` indicating that the client had a birthday but for whatever reason it has been removed.

Here's how the date is laid out. Client's first and last name and class types exists in the client table, while all additional data is **stored in rows** NOT columns in a different table.

I have filtered the table layouts below by `class_type = 2 AND sub_class_type = 5` to simplify the data example.

Based on the table layouts below, I should be returning Client IDs: 5, 11.

Client ID: 5  - has never had a birthday entered.  No row exists.

Client ID: 11 - has had the birthday value removed

My query below is only returning Client ID: 11

**Any help with this would be a lifesaver!**

**Clients Table Layout**

```
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | class_type | sub_class_type |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 5  | Aaron      | Smith     | 2          | 5              |
| 6  | Jenny      | Mackey    | 2          | 5              |
| 11 | Walter     | Walt      | 2          | 5              |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
```

**Clients Additional Table Layout**

```
+----+-----------+------------------------+----------------+
| id | client_id | name                   | value          |
+----+-----------+------------------------+----------------+
| 51 | 5         | work_email_address     | test@test.com  |
| 83 | 6         | date_of_birth          | 07/01/1981     |
| 91 | 6         | work_email_address     | test1@test.com |
| 86 | 11        | cell_phone             | 222-999-8888   |
| 90 | 11        | work_email_address     | test2@test.com |
| 92 | 11        | date_of_birth          |                |
+----+-----------+------------------------+----------------+
```

**My Query**

```
SELECT 
  c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name
FROM 
  app_100_clients AS c 
  LEFT JOIN app_100_client_additional_data AS birthday ON birthday.client_id = c.id 
WHERE 
  c.class_type = 2 
  AND c.sub_class_type = 5 
  AND (
    birthday.name = 'date_of_birth' 
    AND (birthday.value = '') 
    OR (birthday.value = '0') 
    OR (birthday.value = 'false') 
    OR (birthday.value IS NULL)
  )
GROUP BY 
  c.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `birthday.name = 'date_of_birth'` should be in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT 
  c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name
FROM 
  app_100_clients AS c 
  LEFT JOIN app_100_client_additional_data AS birthday
    ON  birthday.client_id = c.id 
    AND birthday.name = 'date_of_birth' 
WHERE 
  c.class_type = 2 
  AND c.sub_class_type = 5 
  AND (
       (birthday.value = '') 
    OR (birthday.value = '0') 
    OR (birthday.value = 'false') 
    OR (birthday.value IS NULL)
  )
GROUP BY 
  c.id
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49cc9e

I would also rewrite the condition for `birthday.value` to

```
AND (
  birthday.value IN ('', '0', 'false') 
  OR birthday.value IS NULL
)
```

or

```
AND coalesce(birthday.value, '') IN ('', '0', 'false')
```

You can also use a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name
FROM app_100_clients AS c 
WHERE c.class_type = 2 
  AND c.sub_class_type = 5
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM app_100_client_additional_data AS birthday
    WHERE birthday.name = 'date_of_birth'
      AND birthday.client_id = c.id
      AND birthday.value NOT IN ('', '0', 'false')
  )
```